# Использование VK Payments API в IFrame-приложениях

Tags: vkontakte-api

[Делаю по примеру](http://www.pvsm.ru/pesochnitsa/82487)

зависает на "ожидание информации о товаре..."
Лог такой

```
Тестовый    Запрос  app_id=6012329&item=item_100coin&lang=ru_RU&notification_type=get_item_test&order_id=1318284&receiver_id=272826680&user_id=272826680
```

Вот ответ

```
Тестовый    Ответ
```

Что не так сделал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось,что не верно передавал параметр Item, нужно чтобы совпадал в запросе и callback